# Print integer vector from Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp

How do I print integer vector from Rcpp function? In my function, I would like to print `IntegerVector` `a`. In R I am calling this function using for example `compnz_next(5,3,c(1,2,2))`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector compnz_next(int n, int k, IntegerVector a) {
  bool more = true;
  int i;
  static int h = 0;
  static int t = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
    a[i] = a[i] - 1;
  }
  if ( 1 < t ) {
    h = 0;
  }

  h = h + 1;
  t = a[h-1];
  a[h-1] = 0;
  a[0] = t - 1;
  a[h] = a[h] + 1;

  more = ( a[k-1] != ( n - k ) );
  Rcout << "a vector is:" << more << std::endl;
  for ( i = 0; i < k; i++ ) {
    a[i] = a[i] + 1;
  }

  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following line:

```
Rf_PrintValue(a);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I am trying to google some documentation on `Rf_PrintValue`, but cannot find anything useful. Where does this function come from?

Comment: It is declared in the header `Rinternals.h` that is pulled in by `RcppCommon.h` that is pulled in by `Rcpp.h` .

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, and a while later, we now have two more options:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction('void printVector(IntegerVector v) { print(v); } ')
R> printVector(c(1L, 3L, 5L))
[1] 1 3 5
```

This just wraps the `Rf_PrintValue()` function from R into an easier to type `print()` function.

```
R> cppFunction('void printVector2(IntegerVector v) { 
+               Rcpp::Rcout << v << std::endl; } ')
R> printVector2(c(1L, 3L, 5L))
1 3 5
R>
```

The (newer) function is implemented via a proper `operator()<<` so that we can just use `<<` as with other C++ types. It also work for numeric vectors and matrices.